# Set up Jedi with virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python

I'm using a `virtualenvwrapper` setup for Python. On my emacs, I have `virtualenvwrapper` and `jedi` installed from MELPA.

What I currently do is, I open Emacs, <kbd>M-x venv-workon RET blabla RET</kbd>, then <kbd>M-x jedi:setup RET</kbd>. Now I have Numpy installed in environment `blabla`, but not globally. After `workon` and restarting of the Jedi server, I anticipate Jedi would auto complete Numpy functions from the package automatically. Say when I type `import numpy; numpy.`, after the dot, I want Jedi to jump out and give me a list of completions. But it doesn't. I tried `jedi:install-server`, it installs it to the old path `~/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default`. I guess Jedi is not reading `virtualenvwrapper` correctly. What's the right way to setup Jedi with `virtualenvwrapper`?

Comment: Jedi.el depends on `(setq python-environment-directory venv-location)`. did you set that up correctly?

Comment: @mutbuerger it seems to be the problem. But do i have to setup that variable every time i do `venv-workon`?

Comment: according to [this discussion](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi/issues/178), it has to be set before the jediepcserver is started.

Comment: @mutbuerger it makes sense, but it's not possible. `venv-workon` isn't that automatic to read `VIRTUAL_ENV` and switch to the appropriate one before starting Emacs. Anyways I changed to Elpy. it sets everything up for me. Thanks for your help